# Firebase child_changed event only triggered by console changes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, onchange, vuejs2

My firebase database looks something like this:

```js
{
    "items": {
        "item": {
            "lastEdit": {
                "timestamp": 2017-05-16T20:55:16.907Z,
                ...
             }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have an initial "child_changed"-listener listening for changes on the "lastEdit"-endpoint like this:

```js
DB.ref("/items/item/lastEdit").on("child_changed", snapshot => {
    // item has changed
});
```

Changing the timestamp value through the firebase console perfectly triggers the child_changed event, but when changing it by updating it from somewhere inside my vue-application nothing happens:

```js
DB.ref("/items/item").update({
    lastEdit: { timestamp: new Date() },
    ...
})
```

Also, when changing the timestamp value using the firebase update method from a **different** device, it triggers the "child_changed"-event on all other devices except for that device.

I am using vuefire and vue.js 2.

Comment: Please share the code that you use to update, since apparently that's the area where the problem is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, i've added some more details.

Comment: any solutions?  Ran into the same problem but with the Go Admin SDK